# .htaccess doesn't work if comment row (# ...) exist

Tags: .htaccess

code below doesn't work my `.htaccess` file. I mean, after this code is applied, I can still index folders in html.

```
# BEGIN disable folder index 
Options All -Indexes
# END disable folder index
```

however, code below works. I mean, after this code is applied, server gives 403 if I try to index a folder which I know that it exists.

`Options All -Indexes`

I'm on a shared hosting and have nothing to do with server config. `.htaccess` is created via notepad++ with encoding setting UTF-8 without BOM. `.htaccess` permission is set to 0644. there exist no other code in `.htaccess`.

what does this situation mean? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely this is a problem with the line breaks. So that for the interpreting part of the http server that "Options" line is not on a separate line, thus also commented out. Check your line ending characters by using a hexeditor. That s the only reliable tool to do so.

Comment: thanks. I will try with a hexeditor. I can not download a hexeditor from my work computer so I'll try it @home.

Comment: Arkascha, I rewrote all codes in notepad and you were right. This time it worked with comments also. Thank you so much. If you transform your comment to an answer I'll accept it. regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like my original comment above pushed you into the right direction:

> Most likely this is a problem with the line breaks. So that for the
>   interpreting part of the http server that "Options" line is not on a
>   separate line, thus also commented out. Check your line ending
>   characters by using a hexeditor. That s the only reliable tool to do
>   so.

Comment: Assuming a Linux server, by any chance did you write the file on a Windows PC and then FTP it in _binary_? An older Mac (x0D line ends) might have a similar problem. Some FTP clients might default to the wrong transfer mode. Also note that many hosts now forbid `Options` commands, although usually you'll get a 500 error rather than its being ignored.

Comment: @PhilPerry Please see the comments made to the question. The issue is already solved.

Comment: I'm just suggesting a reason that it might have ended up with bad line breaks. Maybe the editor had nothing to do with it, and the file was transferred correctly this time. Just something else to consider.

Comment: @PhilPerry Ok, sure, thanks. But then: why should the file have been transferred different after having been created inside another editor? You are right about the old Apple systems line encoding. That was what I also was reminded of. However I also learned that things smelling of line endings usually _do_ have a problem with line endings :-)